# How to still run function when app in background mode?

Tags: ios, swift

when app in background mode , how can it still run function to get api result value.
when result get right value, then update icon badge.

is this possible work?
and how to do ?

thanks for answer me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have tried "macmoonshine" and "Rob"'s  answer and still you not get the badge icon.

Try this. Hope it helps.

**Objective-C**

```
UIUserNotificationSettings* notificationSettings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:notificationSettings];

[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
```

** Swift 3 **

```
let badgeCount: Int = 10
let application = UIApplication.sharedApplication()
application.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Badge, .Sound], categories: nil))        
application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = badgeCount
```

**Swift 3 and with UserNotifications framework**

> import UserNotifications

```
let badgeCount: Int = 10
let application = UIApplication.shared
let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
center.requestAuthorization(options:[.badge, .alert, .sound]) { (granted, error) in
    // Enable or disable features based on authorization.
}
application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = badgeCount
```

Comment: thank you for answer me, but i want to know is , when app in background mode, there is any way to let app still run function to get api result, when get true value, and then change badge, without use push notification and local notification.

Answer (score 0):

Just set [applicationBadgeNumber](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplication/1622918-applicationiconbadgenumber) of `UIApplication` as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Try this **Swift 3**:

```
UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1
```